# Time zone difference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

I'm trying to develop application with rails tutorial.
I'm in chapter 12 and trouble.
When I send the email from password reset form but the reset_at time is added wrong time.
In console, I can get correct time.
Is there anyone who can help me? thanks.

models/user.rb

```
def create_reset_digest
    self.reset_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:reset_digest, User.digest(reset_token))
    update_attribute(:reset_sent_at, Time.zone.now)
end
```

in console("reset_sent_at" is wrong time)

```
>> User.first
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<User id: 1, name: "Example User", email: "example@railstutorial.org", created_at: "2019-12-27 19:18:17", updated_at: "2019-12-29 13:03:12", password_digest: "$2a$10$jbZmEQiB6reX6e/ieGC4wu1lVALDE0GHlkPPeIbUaGe...", remember_`enter code here`digest: nil, admin: true, activation_digest: "$2a$10$t2pk3NPXsvpYcVlrnB4nh.jOZu4YEyKih5wMqneuia2...", activated: true, activated_at: "2019-12-27 19:18:17", reset_digest: "$2a$10$UExX5u5qsCrwuCzyz5xicObm9w98.XWHQuxoDT7vlzC...", reset_sent_at: "2000-01-01 13:03:12">
```

in console(I can get correct time)

```
Time.zone.now
=> Sun, 29 Dec 2019 22:23:40 JST +09:00
>>
```

Why?

Comment: I think the time stamps **are** nearly identical. _2019-12-29 13:03:12_ is just 20 minutes off from  _29 Dec 2019 22:23:40 **JST +09:00**_, just written differently. Did you do the `Time.zone.now` 20 minutes after the update?

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem.
Simply I made a mistake when I add a column to users table like this below.

```
class AddAdtivationToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :users, :activation_digest, :string
    add_column :users, :activated, :boolean, default: false
    add_column :users, :activated_at, :datatime # here is the point of mistake. 
                                                # I should have write ":datetime"
  end
end
```

Comment: This is a very bad antipattern practice to store local time in the DB. The correct approach is to store UTC and convert back to local timezone if needed. You’ll get into many unexpected issues with storing local time.